# ggiraph interactive x scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggiraph

I would like to make the labels on the x-axis interactive in `ggiraph`. Can it be done?

Is there any way to use `scale_discrete_manual_interactive` to accomplish this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggiraph)
my_df <-
  tibble(x=letters[1:5],y=1:5)
my_df |>
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_col_interactive(aes(data_id=x,
                           tooltip=paste(x,y))) ->
  p
  p_obj <- girafe(ggobj = p,
                  height_svg = 3) 
  p_obj
```

Comment: to make the axis _label_ interactive I think you may want `ggiraph::label_interactive`.  See the example in the reference manual pdf on CRAN.

Comment: That's not possible for now. We will try to add that feature in a future version.